# MongoDB Query if (Field A - Field B) > N

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I have been stuck on this for several hours now. I need to write a query that returns all documents where `(Field A - Field B) > N`

```js
// sample data
{ _id: '...', estimated_hours: 0, actual_hours: 0 },
{ _id: '...', estimated_hours: 10, actual_hours: 9 },
{ _id: '...', estimated_hours: 20, actual_hours: 30 }
```

Borrowing answers from [this stack question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16042315/mongo-field-a-greater-than-field-b) I wrote the below, In my mind this should have worked, however I am consistently getting records back that do not match the query...

```rb
## Attempt 1
n = 0
records = API::Record.where('$where': "(this.estimated_hours - this.actual_hours) > #{n}")
## should return the following, but im getting additional records
#=> [{ _id: '...', estimated_hours: 10, actual_hours: 9 }]
```

I know I can likely accomplish this with `$project` however i have to explicitly tell `$project` what fields I want returned. I need all the fields to be returned, we use a third party library that handles pagination

Comment: I don't think `$where: ` is needed, try `.where("(this.estimated_hours - this.actual_hours) > #{n}")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[play](https://mongoplayground.net/p/LVqlFKzx6ng)

```
db.collection.find({
  $where: "(this.estimated_hours - this.actual_hours) > 1"
})
```

[Similar example for reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10987790/mongo-subtract-two-fields)